# Locality parameter not working with googlemapsapi

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have code that used to work great which was taken directly from google developers tools. It is the autocomplete addressform. It still works but it is not saving the city parameter? Everything else is working and even if I check it on the google developers site it does not work? Have they changed something or is there an error they need to know about?

Answer (score 0):

Googlemaps have changed the parameters, locality is now postal_town. I imagine a lot of people may be affected by this. Strange there is no documentation for this change and even their own site has not implemented it??!!!

Comment: This depends on the country and modeling of the data for each country. In one country you can have a locality address component in another postal_town. You should adjust your code according to the country you are working with.

Comment: ? It always worked with exactly the same code provided by google and if you check their own code does not provide it! And hundreds of examples online no longer work, but as I have already provided the answer its not a problem!

Comment: Google can remodel their internal data. By the way, what is the country in question?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, google recently changed this field for UK. I have an web app that depended of this and I had to fix it.